# Ejercicio de herencia en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nos piden realizar este ejercicio y me surgen algunas dudas de las herencias.

Mi solución que no sé si es correcta

```
function Animal(nombre, especie, numPatas, cola) {
this.nombre = nombre;
this.especie = especie;
this.numPatas = numPatas;
this.cola = cola;

this.getNombre = function () {
    return this.nombre;
}

this.setNombre = function (nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

//omito los demás getters y setters

```
function Vaca(nombre, especie, numPatas, cola, leche) {
Animal.call(this, nombre, especie, numPatas, cola);
this.leche = leche;


Vaca.prototype.ordeñar = function (leche) {
    this.leche = this.leche - 1;
}

Vaca.prototype.getLeche = function () {
    return this.leche;
}

    Vaca.prototype.setLeche = function (leche) {
        this.leche = leche;
    }

}

Vaca.prototype = new Animal();

function Tigre(nombre, especie, numPatas, cola, numVictimas) {
Animal.call(this, nombre, especie, numPatas, cola);
this.numVictimas = numVictimas;

Tigre.prototype.getNumVictimas = function () {
    return this.numVictimas;
}

Tigre.prototype.setNumVictimas = function (numVictimas) {
    this.numVictimas = numVictimas;
}

Tigre.prototype.comerPersonas = function (numVictimas) {
    this.numVictimas = this.numVictimas + 1;
}
}

Tigre.prototype = new Animal();
```

Me surge la duda de si es correcta la herencia y qué diferencia habría de hacerlo por ejemplo con prototype

```
function Animal(){     
     this.nombre = nombre;
     this.especie = especie;
     this.numPatas = numPatas;
     this.tieneCola = tieneCola;
    }
    Animal.prototype.getNombre = function(){
     return this.nombre;
    }
    Animal.prototype.setNombre = function(nombre){
     this.nombre = nombre;
    }
```

Comment: por que seguir usando sintáxis de ES5 y no mejor usar la sintáxis de POO en ES6?

Comment: Felipe, [recomiendo que revises esto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Herencia_y_la_cadena_de_protipos). Creo que lo explican con toda claridad, empezando desde el principio. Si es posible en tu ejercicio, yo optaría por la nueva posibilidad que te da ES 2015.

Comment: te dejé un ejemplo en forma de respuesta con comentarios de zonas relevantes del código espero te ayude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Felipe la finalidad de la herencia es precisamente *heredar* los métodos y propiedades del padre.

En el caso que nos ocupa, todos los objetos que extiendan de `Animal` heredarán sus propiedades y sus métodos.

Fíjate que se llama al constructor del padre mediante `super` para asignar las propiedades de éste, y luego, en cada objeto particular se asignan las propiedades que no están en el padre.

Este ejemplo de código muestra más o menos cómo se puede usar un método del padre desde el hijo.

Muestra también algunos controles que se deben establecer en los métodos, como podrás ver en `getMilk` o en `cazar`. Cosas como controlar el tipo de dato, o que no se pidan más litros de leche que los disponibles. Sólo para indicar que los `setter` necesitan muy a menudo controles especiales.

Espero te sirva.

**NOTA:** Este es un modelo parecido al que usamos en lenguajes orientados a objetos. Javascript da la posibilidad de programar así desde ES2015, lo cual no significa que JS sea por ello un POO, como dice MDN:

> Las clases de javascript son introducidas en el ECMAScript 2015 y son
>   una mejora sintáctica sobre la herencia basada en prototipos de
>   JavaScript. La sintaxis de las clases no introduce un nuevo modelo de
>   herencia orientada a objetos a JavaScript. Las clases de JavaScript
>   proveen una sintaxis mucho más clara y simple para crear objetos y
>   lidiar con la herencia.
>
> <sub>[`Classes` en MDN (hay más información interesante en el enlace)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes)</sub>

También hay otras formas de hacerlo.

Este es el código.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(nombre, especie, numPatas, cola) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.especie = especie;
    this.numPatas = numPatas;
    this.cola = cola;
  }

  /*getters
   *--------------------------------------------------------
   *Ninguno de estos getters deben ir 
   *en las otras clases que extiendan de Animal
  */
  getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
  }

  getEspecie() {
    return this.especie;
  }

  getPatas() {
    return this.numPatas;
  }

  getCola() {
    return this.cola;
  }
   /*--------------------------------------------------------*/


  /*setters
   *--------------------------------------------------------
   *Ninguno de estos setters deben ir 
   *en las otras clases que extiendan de Animal
   *NÓTESE que los setters podrían requerir controles especiales
   *según su naturaleza. Como controlar el tipo de dato recibido
   *y cambiar el estado del objeto, sumando, restando, etc.
  */
  
  setNombre(nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }
  setEspecie(especie) {
    this.especie = especie;
  }

  setPatas(patas) {
    this.numPatas = this.numPatas + (patas);
  }

  setCola(cola) {
    this.cola = cola;
  }

}

class Vaca extends Animal {
  constructor(nombre, especie, numPatas, cola, litros) {
    super(nombre, especie, numPatas, cola);
    /*propiedad particular de Vaca*/
    this.litros = litros;
  }


  getMilk(cantidad) {
    var msgInfo = '';
    if (isNaN(cantidad) || cantidad <= 0) {
      msgInfo = 'El dato "' + cantidad + '" no es válido';
    } else {
      var intControl = this.litros - cantidad;
      if (intControl > 0) {
        msgInfo = this.nombre + ' tenía ' + this.litros + ' litros \nSe ordeñaron ' + cantidad + ' y le quedan ' + intControl;
        this.litros = intControl;
      } else {
        msgInfo = this.nombre + ' tiene ' + this.litros + ' litros y estás pidiendo ¡' + cantidad + '! \nNo es posible!';
      }
    }
    console.log(msgInfo);

  }
}

class Tigre extends Animal {
  constructor(nombre, especie, numPatas, cola, victimas, colmillos) {
    super(nombre, especie, numPatas, cola);
    /*propiedad particulares de Tigre*/
    this.victimas = victimas;
    this.colmillos = colmillos;
  }

  //getter y setter de propiedad propia de Tigre
  getColmillos() {
    return this.colmillos;
  }

  setColmillos(colmillos) {
    this.colmillos = this.colmillos + (colmillos);
  }

  cazar(cantidad) {
    var msgInfo = '';
    if (isNaN(cantidad) || cantidad <= 0) {
      msgInfo = 'El dato "' + cantidad + '" no es válido';
    } else {
      var intControl = this.victimas + cantidad;
      this.victimas = intControl;
      msgInfo = `${this.nombre} acaba de cazar ${cantidad}  víctima(s).\nAhora tiene ${intControl}`;
    }
    console.log(msgInfo);
  }
}


/*VACA*/
var objVaca = new Vaca('Milex', 'Mamífero', 4, true, 10);

console.log(objVaca);
objVaca.getMilk(4);

/*Probamos un setter y getter NÓTESE QUE  SON DE LA CLASE Animal*/
objVaca.setNombre('Nueva Milex');
console.log('Ahora el objeto se llama ' + objVaca.getNombre());

/*Probamos algunos controles del ordeñado*/
objVaca.getMilk(-40);
objVaca.getMilk('a');

/*TIGRE*/
var objTigre = new Tigre('TigerHunter', 'Salvaje', 4, true, 30, 8);

/*Veamos el objeto*/
console.log(objTigre);

/*BENEFICIOS DE LA HERENCIA:
 *Podemos usar métodos de la clase Animal y de la clase Tigre
 */
console.log('Me llamo: ' + objTigre.getNombre() + ' y tengo: ' + objTigre.getColmillos() + ' colmillos');

/*El método cazar acumula víctimas*/
objTigre.cazar(3);
objTigre.cazar(0);

/*Modificamos el Tigre, y lo vemos ya viejo :)*/
objTigre.setNombre('TigerHunter ya viejo');
objTigre.setColmillos(-7);
objTigre.setPatas(-1);
objTigre.setCola(false);



console.log(objTigre);
```

Answer (score 3):

### APROVECHA LAS BONDADES DE LA SINTÁXIS DE ES6

Te comento que puedes hacerlo con la sintáxis de ES6, que te brinda los siguientes beneficios:

1. clases regulares
2. constructors
3. setters y getters regulares
4. herencia
5. instanciación

A contianuación te dejo un ejemplo tratando de cubrir los aspecto de tu ejercicio con la sintáxis de ES6, que es nativa de JavaScript moderno y que ya tiene compatibilidad en los navegadores

```
/*clase principal*/
class Animal
  {
    /*constructor actúa como setters*/
    constructor(nombre, especie, numero_patas, cola){
      this._nombre = nombre
      this._especie = especie
      this._numero_patas = numero_patas
      this._cola = cola
    }
  }

/*clase que hereda de Animal*/
class Vaca extends Animal
  {
    /*constructor actúa como setters*/
    constructor(nombre, especie, numero_patas, cola, leche){
      super(nombre, especie, numero_patas, cola)
      this._leche = leche
    }
    /*aquí se declaran los getters*/
    get name(){
      return this._nombre
    }
    get especie(){
      return this._especie
    }

    get patas(){
      return this._numero_patas
    }

    get cola(){
      return this._cola
    }

    get leche(){
      return this._leche
    }

    saca_leche(){
      return `${this._nombre}, ${this._especie}, ${this._numero_patas}, ${this._cola}, ${this._leche = this._leche - 1}`
    }
  }

/*clase que hereda de Animal*/
class Tigre extends Animal
  {
    /*constructor actúa como setters*/
     constructor(nombre, especie, numero_patas, cola, victimas){
      super(nombre, especie, numero_patas, cola)
      this._victimas = victimas
    }
    /*aquí se declaran los getters*/
    get name(){
      return this._nombre
    }
    get especie(){
      return this._especie
    }

    get patas(){
      return this._numero_patas
    }

    get cola(){
      return this._cola
    }

    get victimas(){
      return this._victimas
    }

    comerPersonas(){
      return `El tigre: ${this._nombre}, es ${this._especie}, tiene ${this._numero_patas} patas, ${this._cola}, y se comió a ${this._victimas = this._victimas + 1} pobres personas`

    }
  }

/*la instanción ocurrirá en el objeto obj*/
obj = new Vaca("Pancha", "mamifero", 4, true, 12)
console.log(obj.saca_leche())

/*la instanción ocurrirá en el objeto obj1*/
obj1 = new Tigre("Tigger", "mamifero", 4, true, 4)
console.log(obj1.comerPersonas())
```

---

Que me da como resultado lo siguiente

> "Pancha, mamifero, 4, true, 11" 
> "El tigre: Tigger, es mamifero, tiene
>   4 patas, true, y se comió a 4 pobres personas"