# Problema con variable undefined

Tags: javascript

Necesito mostrar el valor de la variable saldoActual, pero me dice "undefined".

```
function sumarDinero(dinero) {
    saldoCuenta += dinero;
}

var stringDineroADepositar = prompt("Ingrese el monto a depositar");
var dineroADepositar = parseInt(stringDineroADepositar);
var saldoActual = sumarDinero(dineroADepositar);

alert(saldoActual);
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo único que te falta es retornar el valor de la función usando la palabra clave `return`, para que este pueda imprimirse en tu `alert`, así:

```js
var saldoCuenta = 10;
function sumarDinero(dinero) {
    return saldoCuenta += dinero;
}

var stringDineroADepositar = prompt("Ingrese el monto a depositar");
var dineroADepositar = parseInt(stringDineroADepositar);
var saldoActual = sumarDinero(dineroADepositar);

alert(saldoActual);
```

Comment: Gracias! Ahi me salio, pero en el enunciado del ejercicio pedia no utilizar return, hay alguna otra manera de hacelo sin usarlo?

Comment: @MaguiiTa entonces tendrías que colocar todo el código dentro de la función y ejecutarla luego, eso si puedes hacerlo? si deseas lo agrego a la respuesta.

Comment: Creeria que no, porq la funcion solo tiene q declarar la suma

Comment: @MaguiiTa eso no tiene sentido, entonces tienes que usar return si o si, no conozco otro método para devolver el valor de una función

Comment: ok, quizas era un tip tramposo jajaja Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer sin `return` mediante el siguiente procedimiento:

1. Declaras la variable `saldoActual` fuera del ámbito de la función inicializada a `0`, así tendrás acceso a ella dentro y fuera de `sumarDinero` y podrás modificar su valor.
2. Desde dentro de la función, aumentas el valor de la variable con el monto ingresado.
3. Muestras el valor actual de la variable.

Esto es posible porque en todo momento `saldoActual` estará en el ámbito global y podrás acceder a ella desde cualquier parte, para modificarla o mostrarla. No quiere decir que sea le mejor opción. Lo más frecuente en que las funciones de cálculo retornen un valor.

```js
var saldoCuenta = 10;
var saldoActual = 0;

function sumarDinero(dinero) {
  saldoActual = saldoCuenta += dinero;
}

var stringDineroADepositar = prompt("Ingrese el monto a depositar");
var dineroADepositar = parseInt(stringDineroADepositar);
sumarDinero(dineroADepositar);

alert(saldoActual);
```

Aunque no veo la necesidad real de otra variable que se llame `saldoActual` ¿? Si observas, la variable `saldoCuenta` pertenece ya al ámbito global y puedes usarla para mostrar el saldo actual.

Veamos:

```js
var saldoCuenta = 10;
function sumarDinero(dinero) {
  saldoCuenta += dinero;
}

var stringDineroADepositar = prompt("Ingrese el monto a depositar");
var dineroADepositar = parseInt(stringDineroADepositar);
sumarDinero(dineroADepositar);
alert(saldoCuenta);
```

Comment: No lo había pensado así, esa era!

Comment: @BenderPaisa otra forma de hacerlo sería trabajando con objetos. Crearías un objeto `Cuenta` con un método `setSaldo` para modificar el saldo ([ver este ejemplo sobre objetos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/167648/29967)). O sea, hay varias formas de hacerlo sin tener que usar `return`