# Acceso a constructor de una clase desde otra clase

Tags: javascript

me gustaría saber como puedo acceder a la variable la cual guardo en el constructor de Presents,desde la 2 clase Presents2.

Aquí tengo el código:

```
 <h1>Clases</h1>
```

## Clases

```
<script>

class Presents {
    constructor(fecha){
        this.fechVelocity = fecha;
    }

    init(){
        console.log("Inicializar");
        console.log(this.fechVelocity);
        return this.fechVelocity;
    }
}

class Presents2 extends Presents {
    constructor(fechVelocity){
       super();
    }

    init2(){
        console.log("Inicializar2");
        console.log(this.fechVelocity);
    }
}

  let present = new Presents(20192111);
  let present2 = new Presents2();
  present.init();
  present2.init2();
</script>
```

Siempre me sale undefined, y nose como acceder, Teneis idea=

Comment: tu codigo me es extraño, creo que estas confundiendo conceptos, si nos explicas mas lo que quieres hacer probablemente la respuesta seria diferente y mejor

Answer (score 5):

En el ejemplo que muestras `present` y `present2` **serían dos instancias diferentes**, no es que al crear `present` y luego crear `present2` ésta trabajará con lo que ya creaste aquí `let present = new Presents(20192111);`. No es así como funciona la herencia.

Para que `present2` contenga el dato tienes que:

1. Pasar ese dato cuando creas la instancia: **`let present2 = new Presents2(20192111);`**
2. Pasar el dato a la clase padre, usando el método `super` en `Presents2`

Vamos a corregir:

```js
class Presents {
    constructor(fecha){
        this.fechVelocity = fecha;
    }

    init(){
        console.log("Inicializar");
        console.log(this.fechVelocity);
        return this.fechVelocity;
    }
}

class Presents2 extends Presents {
    constructor(fechVelocity){
       super(fechVelocity); //Esto es fundamental
    }

    init2(){
        console.log("Inicializar2");
        console.log(this.fechVelocity);
    }
}

  let present = new Presents(20192111);
  let present2 = new Presents2(20192111); //Esta es una nueva instancia, debes pasar el dato al constructor
  present.init();
  present2.init2();
```

En cuanto al método `init2()`, éste sólo tendría sentido si hiciera **algo distinto** a lo que hace en la clase padre. Si es para hacer lo mismo, no tienes que declarar de nuevo un método similar, sino usar el del padre.

Veamos un ejemplo donde un objeto del tipo `Presents2` puede usar el método `init()` de `Presents`:

```js
class Presents {
    constructor(fecha){
        this.fechVelocity = fecha;
    }

    init(){
        console.log("Inicializar... estamos en el padre");
        console.log(this.fechVelocity);
        return this.fechVelocity;
    }
}

class Presents2 extends Presents {
    constructor(fechVelocity){
       super(fechVelocity); //Esto es fundamental
    }

}

  let present = new Presents(20192111);
  let present2 = new Presents2(20200822); //Esta es una nueva instancia, debes pasar el dato al constructor
  present.init();
  present2.init(); //Este es el método init de Presents
```

---

Este es uno de los aspectos fundamentales de la *herencia*.

Si, como dices en tu comentario, quieres evitar pasar **de nuevo la fecha a `present2`**, lo único que tienes que hacer es crear un solo objeto del tipo `Presents2`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
class Presents {
    constructor(fecha){
        this.fechVelocity = fecha;
    }

    init(){
        console.log("Inicializar... estamos en el padre");
        console.log(this.fechVelocity);
        return this.fechVelocity;
    }
}

class Presents2 extends Presents {
    constructor(fechVelocity){
       super(fechVelocity); //Esto es fundamental
    }

}

  let present2 = new Presents2(20192111);
  present2.init(); //Este es el método init de Presents
```

> En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/167648/29967) tienes un ejemplo más completo que explica cómo
>   funciona la herencia.

Comment: Hola lo que no quiero es volver a pasarle una fecha a presents2 , dado que se la estoy pasando a presents, es decir quiero usar únicamente la fecha de presents desde algun metodo de presents2.

Comment: @otacon070 si lees bien mi respuesta al principio podrás quizá caer en la cuenta de que tu enfoque es equivocado. ¿Por qué sería necesario pasarle de nuevo la fecha a `presents2`? Si lo que quieres es eso, crea un objeto del tipo `Presents2` y listo. Si creas una instancia de un objeto y luego otra, esos objetos no son intercambiables. Incluso si creas dos objetos distintos del tipo `Presents` y a uno no le pasas la fecha, no podrás acceder a ese dato. No sé si me entiendes.

Comment: Si te entiendo, Presents2 es para mas cosas, es una clase que instancia mas cosas por detrás, mi idea..que ahora veo que es equivocada, era que la fecha que le paso a las dos clases , fuerá unicamente pasada a la instancia del primer objeto, y desde la clase 2 acceder a la propiedad de fecha de la primera clase, pero veoentonces que eso es imposible no?

Comment: @otacon070 revisa el tercer fragmento de código que puse al final de la respuesta. Ahí se crea un sólo objeto y se usa el método `init` de `Presents`. Este es uno de los aspectos fundamentales de la *herencia*. Quizá la confusión es pensar que cuando heredas tienes que crear instancias tanto del padre como del hijo ¿? **La herencia permite al hijo hacer uso de todo aquello que es del padre**, propiedades, métodos, etc.

Comment: *mi idea..que ahora veo que es equivocada, era que la fecha que le paso a las dos clases , fuerá unicamente pasada a la instancia del primer objeto*. No es que tu idea sea equivocada. Eso se hace en el `super()` de `Presents2`. Pero cuando creas la instancia **tienes que pasarle los parámetros**, si no le pasas parametros la instancia de la clase se crea sin nada, por eso te daba siempre `undefined`.

Comment: Si, efectivamente,era eso, hacer unicamente una instancia de la segunda clase y usar los metodos de la 1 clase, esa era mi fallo, Muchas gracias

Comment: @otacon070 si la respuesta dada resuelve el problema la puedes marcar, para que la pregunta no aparezcan sin resolver y la respuesta pueda servir a futuros usuarios con un problema similar. Saludos.

Comment: @otacon070 ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 1):

Muestra `undefined`, por que no estás pasando los parámetros a la clase padre. Acá adjunto un ejemplo, donde tengo como clase padre "VideoGame", la cual su constructor recibe 2 parámetros : `name` y `publication` y tengo una clase `Fifa` que es la clase que extiende de la clase padre, por lo cual se le envía al constructor los parámetros de la propia clase `Fifa` y además de la super clase que en este caso es `VideoGame`.

```js
class VideoGame {
    constructor(name = '',publication = '' ){
        this.Name = name;
        this.Publication = publication;

    }
    GetName(){
        return this.Name
    }
    GetPublication(){
        return this.Publication
    }
}
class Fifa extends VideoGame {
    constructor(name = '',publication = '', ){
        super(name,publication);

    }
    GetFullNameVideoGame(){
        return (`This is ${this.Name} ${this.Publication}`)
    }
}
const objVideoGame = new VideoGame("MegaMan", "2000");
console.log(objVideoGame.Name)
console.log(objVideoGame.Publication)
const objVideoGameFifa = new Fifa("Fifa EA Sport", "2019");
console.log(objVideoGameFifa.Name)
console.log(objVideoGameFifa.Publication)
console.log(objVideoGameFifa.Name)
console.log(objVideoGameFifa.GetFullNameVideoGame())
```