# orientacion con obejtos y metodos de javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor

necesito que alguien me ayude
soy  nuevo en esto . Estaba realizando un challenge y quede trabado en un ejercicio (aclaro que el challenge ya termino y no lo presente) no estoy buscando que me ayuden a pasar el challenge sino que  me den orientacion para la proxima vez que  lo intente.

pude crear la clase y el bojeto persona pero en addfriend probe con todo lo que se me ocurrio y no lo pude resolver

muchas gracias

```js
*// function crearClasePersona() {
  // Crear una clase para construir objeto de tipo Persona.
  // el constructor debe recibir:
  // nombre (string) , edad (integer) , hobbies (array de strings) , amigos (array de objetos)
  // Esta funcion debe retonar la clase Persona.

  class Persona {
    constructor(nombre,edad,hobbies,amigos) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.edad = edad;
      this.hobbies = hobbies;
      this.amigos = amigos;

    }
//*
    addFriend(nombre, edad) {
      // el metodo addFriend recibe un string nombre y un entero edad y debe agregar un objeto:
      // { nombre: nombre, edad: edad} al arreglo de amigos de la persona.
      // no debe retornar nada.
       



     
    }
```

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/167648/29967) quizá puede ayudarte a aclarar algunas dudas.

Comment: El método para agregar valores a un arreglo se llama [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push). Intenta hacerlo y si continuas teniendo problemas actualiza tu pregunta.